How do I pass arguments through subcommands in Typer
I am very new to typer so this may be an easy one. I want to have an entry-point with a set of command groups, each with subcommands. The groups will specify what happens (get something and put in stdout / write something to file), so will have roughly the same inputs. Something like
# "get" command group
my_app get something --some-input foo --other-input bar

# "write" command group
my_app write something --some-input foo --other-input bar

At the moment my code looks vaguely like
# main.py
import typer

app = typer.Typer()

# Make sub commands and add to main 
get_app = typer.Typer()
app.add_typer(get_app, name="get")

write_app = typer.Typer()
app.add_typer(write_app, name="write")

# Set top level callback with ctx
@app.callback()
def entrypoint(
    ctx: typer.Context,
    some_input: str = "some_default",
    other_input: str = "other_default"
):
    ctx.obj = {
        "some_input": some_input,
        "other_input": other_input
    }


# Use ctx in subcommands
@get_app.command()
def something(ctx: typer.Context):
    print(f"Get with {ctx.obj}")


@write_app.command()
def something(ctx: typer.Context):
    print(f"Write with {ctx.obj}")

The problem I have is that I can't set either of the optional inputs except for at the top level. So e.g. this works fine
$ python main.py \
      --some-input foo \
      write something

Write  with {'some_input': 'foo', 'other_input': 'other_default'}

But this errors
$ python main.py \
      write something \
      --some-input foo

Usage: main.py write something [OPTIONS]
Try 'main.py write something --help' for help.
╭─ Error ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│ No such option: --some-input                                 │                                                              │                                                              │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯

How do I tell subcommands to accept the parents inputs?
